# Header in Print Preview is different from workbook name

Tags: excel

I have an Excel workbook (e.g. Test.xls). Now when I print this, the header on the document should be the name of the document.

However , what I get is a different header when I print the workbook. Pls advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Go to Page Layout ► Page Setup ► Header/Footer ► Custom Header. Do you see `&[File]` in one of the three sections? If you want the workbook's folder location, do you see `&[Path]`?

Comment: I edited it as &[File], but now it shows file name wth the extension 'xls' as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a dynamic value in header or footer of your sheets or an specific sheet :

- You need a macro for updating those values or texts
- In the macro use a code like this :

---

```
Public Sub updateHeaderFooter()
    ' Update Header sections
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "Left Header Value"
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "Center Header Value"
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightHeader = "Right Header Value"
    ' Update Footer sections
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftFooter = "Left Footer Value"
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "Center Footer Value"
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightFooter = "Right Footer Value"
End Sub
```

Above code change the header and footer of current sheet, for other sheets use a sheet variable to specify a sheet.